# Does a non-AL legal character make the entire session non-legal?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league

If a DM allows a person to play a non-legal character in a D&D 5e Adventurers League session, does the entire session become non-legal for all players?

I seem to recall reading that this is the case, but I can't seem to track down the specific rule or reference when I need it.

Answer (score 8):

I've pulled the most relevant sources I could find for you, though there are probably more. This is from the Adventurer's League FAQ:

> Rules from an official D&D Adventurers League
>   source, such as the Adventurers League Player’s
>   Guide (ALPG), the Adventurers League Dungeon
>   Master’s Guide (ALDMG), or this FAQ establish the
>   boundaries for our current campaign.

From the ALDMG, with emphasis added by me:

> As a D&D Adventurers League Dungeon Master, you
>   are empowered to adjudicate the rules as presented
>   by the official materials (PHB, DMG, MM, etc.). **Run
>   the game according to those rules**, but you are the
>   final arbiter of any ambiguities that might arise in
>   doing so.
>   House rules, that is to say rules that you create
>   that aren’t in the official materials such as critical
>   fails, new races, new classes, etc., aren’t permitted
>   for use in D&D Adventurers League play; the
>   Adventurers League uses the rules as presented in
>   the PHB.

If a DM isn't running a game by the Adventurer's League rules, such as by allowing non-legal characters to play, they themselves aren't following the rules.  That would indicate that it isn't a legal game.  Bearing in mind that they're allowed to arbitrate ambiguities, though, if it's uncertain whether a character is legal, and they make the call to continue anyway, the game itself would still be legal by the mighty powers of DM fiat.

If you have any doubt about whether a character is legal, the AL Player's Guide gives you a list of allowable source material for the build and rules on how to make a legal character.